# Taking a property from an image in a collection and adding it to a list to then chart

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a dataset where I have calculated NDVI and added it as a band in each image. I have then masked those images leaving just pixels that meet my NDVI threshold. I have then added the total number of pixels left as a property for each image.

From here I want to extract those values and add them to a list that can be exported or turned into a chart.

Here is the link to my current code and the shapefile that I'm using to define my ROI:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/a462d9b8883925db866451977ac1e1fb
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-agill6/assets/WDPA_WDOECM_Oct2023_Public_555573540_shp-polygons

This is the code used to calculate the pixel count:

```
// add pixel count as a property to the image
var calculatePixelCount = function(image) {
  var pixelCount =image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: smallAlps.geometry(),
    scale: 30, //  adjust the scale to match the image resolution
        maxPixels: 1e9,
  });
  return image.set('NDVI_pixel_count', pixelCount.get('NDVI')); 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to run your analysis because I do not have access to most of the assets you are using, however there is a very straightforward way of turning the properties of any object into an array. My suggestion would be to return a feature collection instead of an image collection using the following syntax (you may need to explicitly cast your output by wrapping your output in `ee.FeatureCollection()`):

```
return ee.Feature(null).set({
  image: image,
  NDVI_pixel_count: pixelCount.get('NDVI')
})
```

Then you can easily join your pixel counts into an array using:

```
var pixelCountArray = outputFeatureCollection.aggregate_array('NDVI_pixel_count')
```

This format can then be exported or used in a chart using `ui.Chart.array.values`.

Comment: You don't need to convert to features; image are features, and you can just call aggregate_array on the image collection.